# How to tell openshift to do npm install to update a package and restart the app?

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift

I have a node.js app on openshift and a package that it uses which I update frequently. So I also put `"mypackage":"latest"` in the packages.json for that reason.

I want to tell openshift to update that package and restart the app.

`rhc app restart` just restarts the app without doing `npm install`

Is there any way to do that?

<sub>(Other than unnecessarily updating app's code and pushing the changes, which is plan B)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to achieve this:

- place a force_clean_build marker - this is not the best way because it can take a lot of time to re-download all the dependencies but definitely works
- create a build or deploy action hook and force update the dependency with npm